# How can I make words wrap around inside a <span>?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```html
<div style="max-width: 10rem">
  <span>Welcome back (said by a person welcoming you back)</span>
</div>
```

The words show in the span and then flow outside of the 10rem div area.

Is there a way that I can make the words wrap around and stay inside of the `<span>`?

Comment: did you try overflow-x: scroll for the div ? is that what you are looking for ?
if not, try word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: Your code is fine, text will breaks in lines, where is problem ? https://jsfiddle.net/wb14kvk0/

Comment: There must be a `whitespace: nowrap;` rule somewhere in the corresponding elements. Check with web inspector. Wrapping the text would be the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we use word wrap when there is a long word in a paragraph or span you can do this for wrapping words

```
<span style="word-wrap: break-word;">Welcome back (said by a person welcoming you back)</span>
```

your current span does not consist of any long word and it's working fine